# How to use CSS variables as background color for keyframe animation in Edge browser

Tags: css, css-animations, microsoft-edge, css-variables, custom-properties

I'm trying to use CSS variables as the background-color values. I got it to work in Chrome but not in Edge browser. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or it is a bug with the Edge browser.

In this example, the square change background-color from blue to red. But in Edge it's remains white.

```css
:root {
  --blue-color: blue;
  --red-color: red; 
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-color: var(--blue-color); }
  100% { background-color: var(--red-color); }
}

#animate-area { 
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;

  animation: animatedBackground 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is temporary work around if anyone needs it: If I use the CSS variable as the static background color, the animation will start to work. This feels totally random but it seems to solve the problem.

```css
:root {
  --blue-color: blue;
  --red-color: red; 
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-color: var(--blue-color); }
  100% { background-color: var(--red-color); }
}

#animate-area { 
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: var(--blue-color); /* this fixed it! */

  animation: animatedBackground 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but within the `var()` you can specify a second parameter as a form of fallback eg: `var(--blue-color, blue)`

Comment: Thank you @SuperDJ. You just taught me something really useful!

Comment: Is it possible to specify the variables on anything other than `:root` to use within keyframes?